# Construct strings in the output by using grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a curl command

```
curl -u user:password -X POST -k http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"type\" : \"folder\", \"repo\" : \"test-repo\", \"path\" : \""App_7.1.2"\", \"modified\" : {\"\$lt\" : \"2017-05-18\"}  })"
```

The output, that I get looks like this:

```
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "test-repo",
  "path" : "App_7.1.2",
  "name" : "66",
  "type" : "folder",
  "size" : 0,
  "created" : "2016-05-26T09:40:03.332+03:00",
  "created_by" : "user",
  "modified" : "2016-05-26T09:40:03.332+03:00",
  "modified_by" : "user",
  "updated" : "2016-05-26T09:40:03.332+03:00"
},{
  "repo" : "test-repo",
  "path" : "App_7.1.2",
  "name" : "67",
  "type" : "folder",
  "size" : 0,
  "created" : "2016-05-31T19:19:35.040+03:00",
  "created_by" : "user",
  "modified" : "2016-05-31T19:19:35.040+03:00",
  "modified_by" : "user",
  "updated" : "2016-05-31T19:19:35.040+03:00"
} ]
```

I add a grep command to the command above and it starts looking like

```
curl -u user:password -X POST -k http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"type\" : \"folder\", \"repo\" : \"test-repo\", \"path\" : \""App_7.1.2"\", \"modified\" : {\"\$lt\" : \"2017-05-18\"}  })" | grep -oP '\"name\" : \K.*' |tr -d '",'
```

and I get an output

```
66
67
```

So I can make an array from these strings by command:

```
($(curl -u user:password -X POST -k http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"type\" : \"folder\", \"repo\" : \"test-repo\", \"path\" : \""App_7.1.2"\", \"modified\" : {\"\$lt\" : \"2017-05-18\"}  })" | grep -oP '\"name\" : \K.*' |tr -d '",'))
```

But what I actually need - is to get an array of Strings like path/name.

So it should be in my case

```
App_7.1.2/66
App_7.1.2/67
```

Could you tell me, how can I do it? I need to join different strings from output by using grep, is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with JSON in Bash I suggest you pipe through [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). I think grep is the wrong tool for this job. This command gives you what you want:

```
curl https://example.com/ | jq --raw-output '.results | .[] | .path + "/" + .name'
```

The jq filters means:

- `.results` - Read the "results" property of your JSON object
- `.[]` - Read each element in the array, one by one
- `.path + "/" + .name` - Concatenate the "path" property, the "/" string and the "name" property of each object

Then we add the `--raw-output` flag to output the result as lines instead of JSON.